# prevent to_nice_yaml from generating aliases

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2, ansible-2.x

Is it possible to force the function `to_nice_yaml` to avoid generating aliases?

The following line in the Ansible template

```
scrape_configs:
    {{ scrape_configs | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) | indent(2,False) }}
```

where

```
common_relabeling:
  - stuff1
  - stuff2

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: process_exporter
    relabel_configs: "{{ common_relabeling }}"
  - job_name: node_exporter
    relabel_configs: "{{ common_relabeling }}"
```

expands in a YAML file using aliases (see below), which I'm not sure is supported by Prometheus' configuration parser. Obviously I'd like to fix it without hardcoding `common_relabeling` in every entry

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: process_exporter
    relabel_configs: &id001
    - stuff1
    - stuff2
  - job_name: node_exporter
    relabel_configs: *id001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just leave the anchor and alias as is.

Prometheus uses the package [`gopkg.in/yaml.v2`](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/config/config.go#L30), and if you read through the documentation of that package, you'll see that it is based on `libyaml`, which has been parsing anchors and aliases for over a decade now. And the documentation for `gopkg.in/yaml.v2` explicitly states that [anchors are supported](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/tree/v2.2.2#compatibility):

> The yaml package supports most of YAML 1.1 and 1.2, including support for anchors, tags ...